# ActiveRecord Mixing Condition + Better Way to Write This

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, conditional-statements

Is there a better way to write this

I have A Condition which previous Look Very clean and easy to understand
like

```
Account.first.websites.last.users.find(:all,
             :conditions => {:country => "XYZ",:status => "Single",:admin => nil)
```

Now the big problem is that user with **admin = false** is not picked up.

i.e I want all the users from a specific country, having status as
"Single" and admin is either "nil" (Null in database) or "false".

I manage to get desired code but doesn't seem to be happy with clarity
of it.

```
Account.first.websites.last.users.find(:all,
    :conditions => ["country = ? AND status = ? AND admin IS NULL OR 
       admin = ?","XYZ","Single","false"])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: what about using named scopes to clarify a bit everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some scopes to model:

```
scope :not_admin, where("admin is null or admin = ?", false)
scope :single, where("status = ?", "single")
scope :from_country, lambda {|country| where("country = ?", country}
```

then use it in controllers:

```
Account.first.websites.last.users.from_country("XYZ").single.not_admin
```

You can also use autogenerated scopes:

```
Account.first.websites.last.users.scoped_by_country("XYZ").scoped_by_status("single").not_admin
```

Here I left only `not_admin` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Account.first.websites.last.users.all(:conditions => ["country = ? AND status = ? AND admin != true","XYZ","Single"])
```

Comment: You may need to use `admin != ?` and add a `true` parameter.